# Is it possible to use GDAL to combine (rather than mosaic) rasters

Tags: python, gdal, gdal-merge

Is there a GDAL command which can combine multiple rasters so that a unique output value is assigned to each unique combination of input values, like the combine command in ArcGIS?

gdal_merge seems to mosaic rasters so it is not exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like Grass' [r.cross](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/r.cross.html)?

Comment: Exactly! Can I do this through GDAL?

Comment: You can do it with some python code. You can use itertools.product to create a list for all possible combinations, and then use the index of that list for a unique value to use in the raster.